# AndEngine Wait then move character

Tags: andengine

I need Suggestion in how can i move my in a step by step move.

i know it incomplete.

need suggestion on delay

```
for (int redmove = Red_Current_Location; redmove < Red_Moving_Location; redmove++) {
    RedCoinSprite.setPosition(Numbers_Text[redmove].getX(), Numbers_Text[redmove].getY(
    thread.sleep(1000);//kinda like this,Because this is very worng.
}
```

Comment: looks like your code is incomplete.

Comment: use moveBy modifier for how much distance to move with specified interval.Put delay modifier and use loopEntity modifier based on your steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spritemoveHandler=  new TimerHandler(time, true,
        new ITimerCallback() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler arg0) 
            {
                            MoveModifier mod=new Modifier(time-1,fromPoint,toPoint);
                            sprite.registerEntityModifier(mod);
                        }

        });
        scene.registerUpdateHandler(mObstacleCreatorTimeHandler);
```

use this handler to move sprite wait for second again move sprite on conti. time interval.

Comment: i think syntax that you gave me is from a different game. i only want for the sprite to blink from tile to tile going to it's goal tile.

Comment: You want to move image from one position to anather or change image on same position.I think you need e.g. 10 images change first image to second stop for some time again change from second to third and stop for some time and so on .. .Weather it is right ?

Answer (score 0):

is This

```
MoveByModifier RedMoveto = new MoveByModifier(100,32*5,32*5);

RedCoinSprite.registerEntityModifier(RedMoveto);
```